# How Do I up an network interface using java?

Tags: java, linux, networking

Let me give some background to the problem first.

I am running an app that will talk over the network to other people running the app. A machine may have several network interfaces on it. When I run in Windows, the app works fine, lets the user select which network/ interface to use etc. When I try to run the same program on linux, it keeps saying all the interfaces are down, even thoughg ifconfig shows them as up.

I will state that their is no network connection on those interfaces. Which granted, may be the problem. I know, on my windows box, running vmware, it shows all 3 networks. So the problem simply might be that java is trying to ping the network before it deems it up. In the linux world, it shows the network interfaces but says that they are all down.

Does java do a ping to establish if the network works? If not, how do I specify to java to "up" the network , like how do i do ifconfig eth0 up, in java lingo.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to run your application using root privilege or running it using `sudo`